Openlayers uses canvas function to return canvas images, How to render in real-time before releasing the mouse button
openlayers uses canvas function to return canvas images, hoping to achieve real-time rendering while dragging the mouse
Only render after releasing the mouse button
How to render in real-time before releasing the mouse button
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import View from "ol/View.js";
import ImageLayer from "ol/layer/Image";
import ImageCanvasSource from "ol/source/ImageCanvas";

var map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  })
});

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

var imageCanvasSource = new ImageCanvasSource({
 canvasFunction: function (extent,resolution,pixelRatio,size,projection) {
  const mapSize = map.getSize();
  canvas.width = mapSize[0];
  canvas.height = mapSize[1];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size[0], size[1]);
  const imageData = ctx.createImageData(mapSize[0], mapSize[1]);
  for (let x = 0; x < mapSize[0]; x += 1) {
    for (let y = 0; y < mapSize[1]; y += 1) {
      const index = (y * mapSize[0] + x) * 4;
      data[index + 0] = getRandomInt(0, 255); // R
      data[index + 1] = getRandomInt(0, 255); // G
      data[index + 2] = getRandomInt(0, 255); // B
      data[index + 3] = 200; // A (opaque)
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return canvas;
 }
})
var imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
 source: imageCanvasSource,
});
map.addLayer(imageLayer);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}


The current effect is to drag the map and release the mouse button to render the image.
The desired effect is to render the image simultaneously while dragging the mouse without releasing the mouse button. Just like tiles。
Previously, there were two similar parameters：
updateWhileAnimating: true,
updateWhileInteracting: true

But it doesn't work on ImageLayer

Those options have only ever been used for vector layers.  For image sources use ratio option to create an oversized canvas which extends beyond the initial viewport.
